# need source value with using change() function

Tags: jquery, onchange

Hi freinds I want to change `image src` on change in `fileField` my code is mentioned below

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileFieldVoice"><br/><br/>
                                  <p>Upload your own voice file 
here only mp3, wav, Max. 4MB</p>
                                  <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                  <p class="center clk"><a href="#"><img src="images/uploadDisable.png" alt=" " width="78" height="37" ></a></p>
```

**Script**

```
$('#fileFieldVoice').on('change',function(){

    var fileField = 'images/uploadActive.png'
/*alert(fileField)*/
$('.clk').children('img').attr('src').val(fileField);

    })
```

You can also see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/QPry4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QPry4/2/)

change this `$('.clk').children('img').attr('src').val(fileField);`

to

`$('.clk').find('img').attr('src', fileField);`

**js**

```
$('#fileFieldVoice').on('change', function () {
    var fileField = 'images/uploadActive.png'
    /*alert(fileField)*/
    $('.clk').find('img').attr('src', fileField); 
})
```

Comment: its working now thanks ... but its not working with children function will u plz explain

Comment: @Kamal The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as wel

Comment: @Kamal `.children()` will search in one level dom in your case `p` child  is `a` so it does not go through the grandchildren(i.e `img` in your case ).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35349/discussion-between-kamal-and-tushar-gupta)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/QPry4/7/

```
$('#fileFieldVoice').on('change',function(){    
    var fileField = 'http://blog.jtclark.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/apple-logo1-64x64.jpg'
    $('.clk').find('img').attr('src', fileField);
    })
```

Note: Just for my reference i used the image available at net.